# How do the functions-wrappers interact?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm studying this project: [rsa-aes-client-server](https://github.com/weblab-technology/rsa-aes-client-server-encryption-nodejs-example)
and I can not understand how they interact wrapper-functions (aes-wrapper and rsa-wrapper) in folders "\componnets\" and "\static\js\"? and how these functions then interact with the index.js file?
static\js\rsa-wrapper.js:

```js
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var crypto = window.crypto.subtle;
    var rsaParams =  {name:"RSA-OAEP", hash: {name: "SHA-1"}};

    function importPublicKey(keyInPemFormat){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var key = converterWrapper.convertPemToBinary2(keyInPemFormat);
            key = converterWrapper.base64StringToArrayBuffer(key);

            crypto.importKey('spki', key, rsaParams, false, ["encrypt"])
                .then(function(cryptokey) {
                    resolve(cryptokey);
                });
        });
    }

    function importPrivateKey(keyInPemFormat){

        var key = converterWrapper.convertPemToBinary2(keyInPemFormat);
        key = converterWrapper.base64StringToArrayBuffer(key);

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            crypto.importKey('pkcs8', key, rsaParams, false, ["decrypt"])
                .then(function(cryptokey) {
                    resolve(cryptokey);
                });
        });
    }

    function publicEncrypt(keyInPemFormat, message) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            importPublicKey(keyInPemFormat).then(function (key) {
                crypto.encrypt(rsaParams, key, converterWrapper.str2abUtf8(message))
                    .then(function(encrypted){
                        resolve(converterWrapper.arrayBufferToBase64String(encrypted));
                    });
            })
        });
    }

    function privateDecrypt(keyInPemFormat, encryptedBase64Message) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            importPrivateKey(keyInPemFormat).then(function (key) {
                crypto.decrypt(rsaParams, key, converterWrapper.base64StringToArrayBuffer(encryptedBase64Message))
                    .then(function(decrypted){
                        resolve(converterWrapper.arrayBufferToUtf8(decrypted));
                    });
            });
        });
    }

    window.rsaWrapper = {
        importPrivateKey: importPrivateKey,
        importPublicKey: importPublicKey,
        privateDecrypt: privateDecrypt,
        publicEncrypt: publicEncrypt
    }

}());
```

components\rsa-wrapper.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const rsaWrapper = {};
const fs = require('fs');
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// load keys from file
rsaWrapper.initLoadServerKeys = (basePath) => {
    rsaWrapper.serverPub = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(basePath, 'keys', 'server.public.pem'));
    rsaWrapper.serverPrivate = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(basePath, 'keys', 'server.private.pem'));
    rsaWrapper.clientPub = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(basePath, 'keys', 'client.public.pem'));
};

rsaWrapper.generate = (direction) => {
    let key = new NodeRSA();
    key.generateKeyPair(2048, 65537);
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'keys', direction + '.private.pem'), key.exportKey('pkcs8-private-pem'));
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'keys', direction + '.public.pem'), key.exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem'));

    return true;
};

rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt = () => {
    console.log('Server public encrypting');

    let enc = rsaWrapper.encrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPub, 'Server init hello');
    console.log('Encrypted RSA string ', '\n', enc);
    let dec = rsaWrapper.decrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPrivate, enc);
    console.log('Decrypted RSA string ...');
    console.log(dec);
};

rsaWrapper.encrypt = (publicKey, message) => {
    let enc = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: publicKey,
        padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, Buffer.from(message));

    return enc.toString('base64');
};

rsaWrapper.decrypt = (privateKey, message) => {
    let enc = crypto.privateDecrypt({
        key: privateKey,
        padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, Buffer.from(message, 'base64'));

    return enc.toString();
};

module.exports = rsaWrapper;
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const rsaWrapper = require('./components/rsa-wrapper');
const aesWrapper = require('./components/aes-wrapper');

rsaWrapper.initLoadServerKeys(__dirname);
rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt();

// middleware for static processing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// web socket connection event
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // Test sending to client dummy RSA message
    let encrypted = rsaWrapper.encrypt(rsaWrapper.clientPub, 'Hello RSA message from client to server');
    socket.emit('rsa server encrypted message', encrypted);

    // Test accepting dummy RSA message from client
    socket.on('rsa client encrypted message', function (data) {
        console.log('Server received RSA message from client');
        console.log('Encrypted message is', '\n', data);
        console.log('Decrypted message', '\n', rsaWrapper.decrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPrivate, data));
    });

    // Test AES key sending
    const aesKey = aesWrapper.generateKey();
    let encryptedAesKey = rsaWrapper.encrypt(rsaWrapper.clientPub, (aesKey.toString('base64')));
    socket.emit('send key from server to client', encryptedAesKey);

    // Test accepting dummy AES key message
    socket.on('aes client encrypted message', function (data) {
        // console.log('Server received AES message from client', '\n', 'Encrypted message is', '\n', data);
        console.log('Decrypted message', '\n', aesWrapper.decrypt(aesKey, data));

        // Test send client dummy AES message
        let message = aesWrapper.createAesMessage(aesKey, 'Server AES message');
        socket.emit('aes server encrypted message', message);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: When you call `require('./filename')` in `index.js` file it imports whatever is declared in `madule.exports` in required filename. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The best way to figure out how things work is to use a debugger. Step through the code line by line and watch the interesting variables. It's also good practice for when you need to do this with your own code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm just starting to learn the web. Could you give a link to the manual for using the debugger?

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/988363)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/
Or just do a search of the internet for "how to debug javascript"...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the links you provide are for the browser when he asks about nodejs..

Comment: @MotiKorets There is nothing in the question which indicates nodejs. The tags are `javascript` and `web`. If you know it to be relevant, perhaps you could *help* by editing the question to include the appropriate tag?

Comment: @UserLevel0 There is a page on Node's website, which even has [a guide to debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files under `static/js` file are loaded on the client side and expose a global variable for example in `rsa-wrapper` this code will add a global variable `rsaWrapper` that will be used in `index.html`

```
window.rsaWrapper = {
        importPrivateKey: importPrivateKey,
        importPublicKey: importPublicKey,
        privateDecrypt: privateDecrypt,
        publicEncrypt: publicEncrypt
    }
```

The files in `componnets` are used on the server side and loaded with `require` statement.
The client server interaction is made with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) library which provides a way for two way client server interactions.
The calls are done with `socket.emit` to send messages and `socket.on` to listen to messages